# How to remove files in Team City?

Tags: teamcity

I am using Team City to deploy an ASP.NET Website.My Issue is Artifact folder contains .cs and designer files too. How to remove these type of files from Artifact folder. For ASP.NET websites we do not need such files.Need files like ASCX,ASPX,JS,CSS etc only.

Comment: Set your artifact paths correctly.

Comment: @Amy I want remove cs files. I have set by Artifact path to Root

Comment: Set your artifact paths more explicitly, so they don't include the .cs files.  The object isn't to *remove* them, it's to *not include them* in the first place.

Comment: @Amy What is the format of removing files with specific extensions in Team City Artifact ?

Comment: There isn't one.  You have to only include the files you want.

Comment: @Amy See I have 100's of files in different folders in my project

Comment: And?  That doesn't change what you have to do.  I cannot go to chat.

Comment: @Amy Is it unable to exclude files with specific extension ?

Comment: @James This is the simple workaround you can try. Add Delete folder command after all the TeamCity builds. For e.g. RD /S /Q C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx

Answer (score 0):

Using Publish Profiles and Web Deploy to generate a deployment package, you can specify that only files required to run the application are captured as artifacts in TeamCity.

**Update Visual Studio Project Properties**:
[Choose "Only files needed to run this application" in the Package/Publish Web section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK3pU.png)

**Create a Visual Studio Publish Profile**:
[Set Web Deploy as the Publish Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOTMh.png)

**Update TeamCity Build Runner**: Add */p:PublishProfile="[name of publish profile created in previous step]"* to the Command Line Parameters

**Update TeamCity Artifact Path**: [your source path]\obj\[VS build configuration]\Package\** => artifacts\[your desired path and file name].zip

Unfortunately I can't add any more screenshots due to rep.  Hope this helps!